# httplib exception while runing selenium thread in the background

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, httplib

I am trying to run a thread in the background during testing that keeps track of all unique domains visited during testing. I am starting the thread when the browser is opened and eventually clearing all the cookies of the domains that were visited when the tear down keyword `Reset Browser` is called. The background thread is currently working without any errors. However, my Robot Framework tests are failing at random points logging either a CannotSendRequest or ResponseNotReady error. I think this is because my background thread is periodically requesting the current URL from webdriver and causing an interrupt.

I'm wondering if there is a way to prevent these errors from being thrown? I'm aware webdriver is not thread-safe but was hoping for a work around.

```
class TrackingThread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, webdriver, *args, **kwargs):
        #super(TrackingThread, self).__init__()
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.webdriver = webdriver
        self.domains = set()

    def run(self):
        while str(self.webdriver)!="None" and not self.stopped():
            try:
                uri = urlparse.urlsplit(self.webdriver.get_location())
            except Exception, e:
                if (str(e) == "[Errno 111] Connection refused" or "chrome not reachable" in str(e) or str(e) == "No browser is open"):
                    break
            if uri.netloc:
                self.domains.add('{uri.scheme}://{uri.netloc}/'.format(uri=uri))
            sleep(0.2)

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()
        return self.domains

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()

    def clear_domains(self):
        self.domains = set();

    def get_domains(self):
        return self.domains

def initialize_unique_domain_tracking(self):
    try:
        tracking_thread = self.TrackingThread(target=self.TrackingThread, name="Tracking", webdriver=self)
        tracking_thread.start()
        return tracking_thread
    except Exception,e:
        return False;
```

I'm using chromedriver version 2.29.461571 and Chromium 58.0.3029.110

Comment: Have you tried to use Pabot for running multiple test cases in parallel instead of threading?

Comment: Unfortunately my SUT prevents me from running all my tests with pabot. I am not doing this to run tests in parallel. I want to be able to keep track of domains visited during testing so that I can clear all cookies and re use the current browser for all tests. This will save me a lot of time by not having to constantly open and close browsers. I have another implementation of this idea but it will only work when I expect a page change, I would like to make this system able to track all domains so that it is more reliable. The old system is no longer sufficient as my SUT has changed.

Comment: In my mind the benefit of having a stable fresh browser at the start of every test outweighs the cost of time needed to restart the browser. Some of this cost is often mitigated by running tests in parallel. By sticking with a single browser, a lot of complexity is needed to clear caches, remove cookies and setup the browser for the next test. To me this sounds more complex and brittle and would not be my first choice.

Comment: I understand your point, but I've been using a system similar to this for over a year and there has been no hiccups. From my experience, cleaning up the browser is very easy once you know the domains visited during testing. I personally think this is worth doing as I save a significant amount of time during my regression testing.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using a seperate thread for maintaining the visited URL's instead of using the `Selenium2Library.Get Location` keyword in `[Teardown]`

Comment: A test can visit many different domains during testing so a test teardown to get the location would not work. Unless I am misunderstanding you?

Comment: Well, I'm assuming that there are one or two keywords that initiate a change in URL. For example a click, or an explicit URL change. If these are custom ones, then in the keyword `[Teardown]` add this so that it always gets executed. However, it's a keyword that can be used at any point in time and returns the present URL.